# Is there a name for music where only the bass instruments are used

Tags: terminology, bass-guitar

I just love the bass, there are youtube channels with bass players that just do bass solo. Is there a name for this.

I can't find anything on spotify that resembles for example this:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn’t a specific name for music that has only bass (maybe “solo bass music”?). Off the top of my head the only record that comes to mind that is solo bass is a classical record, Edgar Meyer playing the Bach cello suites. I’m sure there are some others. Your best bet is to search for albums where the bassist is the leader/featured artist. There may or may not be solo pieces on them but the bass will probably be featured prominently on a few tunes. Also you must check out “Big Bottom” by Spinal Tap, just basses, drums and vocals, bass heaven!

Comment: @Tetsujin I went to see a buddy of mine playing guitar with Paul Schaffer here in Vegas in 2019 and they played “Big Bottom” with about 5 bass players on stage! Will Lee was in town and played with them, it was a gas!

Comment: In a more serious vein, ex-Minutemen bassist Mike Watt and ex-Black Flag bassist Kira Roessler has a bass duet project called dos.